# How does the order of Q affect the time it takes to solve ECDLP?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

I use Sagemath's built-in function `discrete_log()` to solve ECDLP and according to the documentation it uses Pohling-Hellman algorithm to solve an ECDLP.

This is the case for my EC:

```
P-order => 176648753626148987385153422443570230330
Q-order() => 2
```

The P-order has these prime factors: 2 * 3 * 5 * 5888291787538299579505114081452341011

Even though the highest prime factor is super-large, the ECDLP through `discrete_log()` is solved within a second.

I Read about the Pohling-hellman attack and it only mentions that P should have small prime-factors in order for the attack to be successful. It never mentions the order of Q.

How does the order of Q affect the time it takes for the attack to be successful?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I believe Sagemath is doing:

- Given the problem of finding $x$ s.t. $xP = Q$, one step is computing $x' = x \bmod 5888291787538299579505114081452341011$; it does this by computing $P' = (2\cdot 3 \cdot 5)P$, and $Q' = (2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5)Q$, and trying to solve $x'P' = Q'$
- As the order of $P'$ is circa $2^{122}$, we would normally expect this computation to take circa $2^{61}$ time (quite a while).  However, in this case, $Q'$ is the neutral element.  I suspect that Sagemath notices this, and so immediately concludes that $x' = 0$
- Every other computation involved in Pohlig-Hellman is relatively quick, and so it reports the answer ($3 \cdot 5 \cdot 5888291787538299579505114081452341011$) quickly.

The summary is: if your implementation special cases this $Q' = 0$ case, then we can skip any prime that does not appear in the order of $Q$; the time taken by Polhig-Hellman is dominated by the largest prime that appears both in the order of $P$ and the order of $Q$.

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on this. This is exactly what I wanted to know because in literature it's always mentioned only the order of P. Your answer makes complete sense, especially considering that I had another case where the order of Q was very large and even though the prime factors were small, it took way more time to compute the discrete log.